# An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Failed to launch Appium Settings app: Condition unmet after

Tags: appium, appium-android, inspector

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Failed to launch Appium Settings app: Condition unmet after 5398 ms. Timing out.

{
"platformName": "android",
"platformVersion": "9",
"deviceName": "redmi Y2",
"noReset": "True",
"appPackage": "com.pc360.appmedevantage",
"appActivity": "com.pc360.appmedevantage.MainActivity",
"automationName": "uiautomator2",
}

Comment: Welcome. Would be great to ask a question including a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).